# How to sum up every column of a Scala array?

Tags: arrays, scala

If I have an array of array (similar to a matrix) in Scala, what's the efficient way to sum up each column of the matrix? For example, if my array of array is like below:

```
val arr =  Array(Array(1, 100, ...), Array(2, 200, ...), Array(3, 300, ...))
```

and I want to sum up each column (e.g., sum up the first element of all sub-arrays, sum up the second element of all sub-arrays, etc.) and get a new array like below:

```
newArr = Array(6, 600, ...)
```

How can I do this efficiently in Spark Scala?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [breeze](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze) `Vector`:

```
scala> val arr =  Array(Array(1, 100), Array(2, 200), Array(3, 300))
arr: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1, 100), Array(2, 200), Array(3, 300))

scala> arr.map(breeze.linalg.Vector(_)).reduce(_ + _)
res0: breeze.linalg.Vector[Int] = DenseVector(6, 600)
```

If your input is sparse you may consider using `breeze.linalg.SparseVector`.

Comment: https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Breeze-Linear-Algebra has useful reference functions for this sort of thing, though it assumes you're using Scala / Breeze data types (e.g. DenseMatrix) instead of an Array of Arrays.

Answer (score 6):

There is a suitable [`.transpose` method](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@transpose[B](implicitasTraversable:A=%3Escala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B]):CC[CC[B]@scala.annotation.unchecked.uncheckedVariance]) on `List` that can help here, although I can't say what its efficiency is like:

```
arr.toList.transpose.map(_.sum)
```

(then call `.toArray` if you specifically need the result as an array).

Comment: Also works without `toList`: `arr.transpose.map(_.sum) #=> res24: Array[Int] = Array(6, 600)`

Comment: Apparently requires all input arrays to be the same length, I get an error otherwise.

Comment: @MichaelKohl So it does, I must have made a mistake when I tried it directly on the initial array.

Comment: @Paul Yes, it specifically warns about that in the (expanded) docs for `List` - doesn't seem to mention it in the docs for `Array`, though.

Comment: The mention of Spark makes me think the array can be quite big. Transposing that isn't probably the best approach

Comment: @Shadowlands how can we do if we have randomly generated spark.liang.Densematrix? for example A= DenseMatrix.randn(m,n,rng). how make column or row wise sum of Matrix A

Answer (score 4):

In practice a linear algebra vector library as mentioned by @zero323 will often be the better choice.

If you can't use a vector library, I suggest writing a function `col2sum` that can sum two columns -- even if they are not the same length -- and then use `Array.reduce` to extend this operation to N columns.  Using reduce is valid because we know that sums are not dependent on order of operations (i.e. 1+2+3 == 3+2+1 == 3+1+2 == 6) :

```
def col2sum(x:Array[Int],y:Array[Int]):Array[Int] = {
    x.zipAll(y,0,0).map(pair=>pair._1+pair._2)
}

def colsum(a:Array[Array[Int]]):Array[Int] = {
    a.reduce(col2sum)
}

val z = Array(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Array(2, 4, 6, 8, 10), Array(1, 9));

colsum(z)

--> Array[Int] = Array(4, 15, 9, 12, 15)
```

Comment: Nicely done, especially as it can be expressed quite succinctly: `arr.reduce(_.zipAll(_,0,0).map{case (a,b) => a+b})`

Comment: @jwh Do you *need* the case statment, as there is only one case?

Comment: Well there are a number of ways to sum a Tuple2 (Int,Int).  Your code breaks the received argument, a tuple, into its _1 _2 parts, which is good and straight forward.  I chose the "partial function" method, which requires braces `{}` and the `case` statement, because I find it a little less visually cluttered.  The `case` is needed to invoke pattern matching, which then assigns each part to the designated variables (`a` and `b`).

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> val arr =  Array(Array(1, 100), Array(2, 200), Array(3, 300 ))
arr: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1, 100), Array(2, 200), Array(3, 300))

scala> arr.flatten.zipWithIndex.groupBy(c => (c._2 + 1) % 2)
       .map(a => a._1 -> a._2.foldLeft(0)((sum, i) => sum + i._1))

res40: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(2 -> 600, 1 -> 6, 0 -> 15)
```

**flatten** array and **zipWithIndex** to get index and **groupBy** to map new array as column array, foldLeft to sum the column array.