# groupBy on multiple values

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a list of `calls`, `smsIn`, `smsOut` in a CSV file, and I want to count the number of smsIn/smsOut for each Phone number.

CallType indicates the type (`call`, `smsIn`, `smsOut`)

An example of the data is (`phoneNumber`, `callType`)

```
7035076600, 30 
5081236732, 31
5024551234, 30
7035076600, 31
7035076600, 30
```

Ultimately, I want something like this: `phoneNum`, `numSMSIn`, `numSMSOUt`
I have implemented something like this:

```
val smsOutByPhoneNum = partitionedCalls.
                       filter{ arry => arry(2) == 30}.
                       groupBy { x => x(1) }.
                       map(f=> (f._1,f._2.iterator.length)).
                       collect()
```

The above gives the number of SMS out for each phone number. Similarly

```
val smsInByPhoneNum = partitionedCalls.
                      filter{ arry => arry(2) == 31}.
                      groupBy { x => x(1) }.
                      map(f => (f._1, f._2.iterator.length)).
                      collect()
```

The above gives the number of SMS in for each phone number.

Is there a way where I can get both done in one iteration instead of two.

Comment: Why was this question flagged down. Is it not a valid question ? Is it offensive to anybody? or is it a duplicate ?... I will appreciated it if somebody will give a reason for flagging this down.  Flagging down without reason is very rude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great answer @zero323

```
val partitionedCalls = sc.parallelize(Array(("7035076600", "30"),   
("5081236732", "31"), ("5024551234", "30"),("7035076600", "31"), 
("7035076600", "30")))

# count the pairs <(phoneNumber, code), count>
val keyPairCounts = partitionedCalls.map((_,1))
# using reduceByKey
val aggregateCounts = keyPairCounts.reduceByKey(_ + _).map{ case((phNum,  
inOrOut), cnt) => (phNum, (inOrOut, cnt)) }
# using groupBy to aggregate and merge similar keys
val result = aggregateCounts.groupByKey.map(x => (x._1, 
x._2.toMap.values.toArray))

# collect the result 
result.map(x => (x._1, x._2.lift(0).getOrElse(0), 
x._2.lift(1).getOrElse(0))).collect().map(println)
```

Reference:
A good explanation on difference between groupBy and reduceBy:[prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html)

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways you can solve this problem. A naive approach is to aggregate by (number, type) tuple and group partial results:

```
val partitionedCalls = sc.parallelize(Array(
  ("7035076600", "30"), ("5081236732", "31"), ("5024551234", "30"),
  ("7035076600", "31"), ("7035076600", "30")))

val codes = partitionedCalls.values.distinct.sortBy(identity).collect    

val aggregated = partitionedCalls.map((_, 1L)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
  .map{case ((number, code), cnt) => (number, (code, cnt))}
  .groupByKey
  .mapValues(vs => {
    codes.map(vs.toMap.getOrElse(_, 0))
  })
```

You can also `map` and `reduceByKey` with some structure which can capture all counts:

```
case class CallCounter(calls: Long, smsIn: Long, smsOut: Long, other: Long)

partitionedCalls
  .map { 
    case (number, "30") => (number, CallCounter(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)) 
    case (number, "31") => (number, CallCounter(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L)) 
    case (number, "32") => (number, CallCounter(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)) 
    case (number, _)    => (number, CallCounter(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)) 
  }
  .reduceByKey((x, y) => CallCounter(
    x.calls + y.calls, x.smsIn + y.smsIn, 
    x.smsOut + y.smsOut, x.other + y.other))
```

or even combine `map` and `reduce` steps in a single `aggregateByKey`:

```
val transformed = partitionedCalls.aggregateByKey(
  scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.empty[String,Long].withDefault(_ => 0L)
)(
  (acc, x) => { acc(x) += 1; acc },
  (acc1, acc2) => { acc2.foreach{ case (k, v) => acc1(k) += v }; acc1 }
).mapValues(codes.map(_))
```

Depending on a context you should adjust accumulator class so it better suits your needs. For example if number of classes is large you should consider using linear algebra libraries like `breeze` - see [How to sum up every column of a Scala array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32878818/1560062)

One thing you definitely should avoid is to `groupBy` + `map` when you really mean `reduceByKey`. It has to shuffle all the data when all you want is just a modified word count.

Comment: Good solution, with both the CallCounter class, and aggregateByKey.. I ended up using aggregateByKey. Also good suggestion to use reduceByKey, instead of groupBy + map. It helped me negate a performance issue that would have happened down the line in production.

Answer (score 1):

The result codes are counterintuitive, butnevertheless:

This codes:

```
object PartitionedCalls {
  def authorVersion(partitionedCalls: Seq[Seq[Long]]) ={
    val smsOutByPhoneNum = partitionedCalls.
      filter{ arry => arry(1) == 30}.
      groupBy { x => x(0) }.
      map(f=> (f._1,f._2.iterator.length))

    val smsInByPhoneNum = partitionedCalls.
      filter{ arry => arry(1) == 31}.
      groupBy { x => x(0) }.
      map(f => (f._1, f._2.iterator.length))

    (smsOutByPhoneNum, smsInByPhoneNum)
  }

  def myVersion(partitionedCalls: Seq[Seq[Long]]) = {
    val smsInOut = partitionedCalls.
      filter{ arry => arry(1) == 30 || arry(1) == 31}.
      groupBy{ _(1) }.
      map { case (num, t) =>
        num -> t.
          groupBy { x => x(0) }.
          map(f=> (f._1,f._2.iterator.length))
      }

    (smsInOut(30), smsInOut(31))
  }
}
```

implement these tests:

```
class PartitionedCallsTest extends FunSuite {
  val in = Seq(
    Seq(7035076600L, 30L),
    Seq(5081236732L, 31L),
    Seq(5024551234L, 30L),
    Seq(7035076600L, 31L),
    Seq(7035076600L, 30L)
  )

  val out = (Map(7035076600L -> 2L, 5024551234L -> 1L),Map(7035076600L -> 1L, 5081236732L -> 1L))

  test("Author"){
    assert(out == PartitionedCalls.authorVersion(in))
  }

  test("My"){
    assert(out == PartitionedCalls.myVersion(in))
  }
}
```

Comment: This is good and works, but agree with zero323, about groupBy + map  will lead to excessive shuffling especially when he data size is large.