# How to sum every value in scala vector

Tags: scala, vector, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

i have a collection of Vectors as

```
var coefficentsList = new MutableList[Vector]
```

I want to sum each element of the individual vector to each column of other vectors such. eg The coefficentsList will have the following vectors:

```
v1 = [0.2, 0.4, 0.1]
v2 = [0.4, 0.5, 0.1]
v3 = [0, 0, 0.3]
```

So I'd want the resultant vector like

```
V = [0.6, 0.9, 0.5]
```

Now to do this, i came across the breeze vectors [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878818/how-to-sum-up-every-column-of-a-scala-array) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28232829/addition-of-two-rddmllib-linalg-vectors) so i wrote the following code :

```
coefficentsList.toArray.map{
  Vector(_).reduce(_ + _)
}
```

but its giving me a type mismatch exception : found Array[Double], required : String

Is there any other way to do this as I'm stumped with this

Comment: a `Vector` needs a type parameter so first, fix you type errors. Also, why did you need to use `toArray` ? Use `map` directly on your `MutableList` no ?

Comment: @alifirat This can be `scala.collection.immutable.Vector`, `breeze.linalg.Vector` or `o.a.s.mllib.linalg.Vector` -  it is not even clear from the context.

Comment: @zero323 It is indeed o.a.s.mllib.linalg.Vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip` achieves right what you need

```
val coefficientsList = List(
  Vector(0.2, 0.4, 0.1),
  Vector(0.4, 0.5, 0.1),
  Vector(0.0, 0.0, 0.3)
)

val result = coefficientsList.reduceLeft { (acc, vec) =>
  acc zip vec map {
    case (a, b) => a + b
  }
}
// result: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Double] = Vector(0.6, 0.9, 0.5)
```

Comment: But doesn't parallelize (which is the reason for using `reduce`)